# How many Connections are created to Kafka brokers from a application

Tags: java, apache-kafka

In my application I am having around 40 different topics. Currently working on RabbitMQ, planning to move to Kafka. Each topic I am thinking to have 10 partitions (As having multiple instances of this application running and want to have load distributed among at least 10 nodes).
Also, based on different serializers I require, I am planning to have 5 producers.
So, on a JVM, will have 40 Consumers running(1 per topic) and 5 producers running.
Planning to have Kafka cluster of 9 brokers.

I tried browsing relation, where I found some links suggesting that the connection keeps alive, but could not get concrete answer about how many connection will be created from a JVM on basis of Producer count, Topic count, partition count, consumer count and Broker count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maxiumum consumer connection limit is one per partition, per topic; 40 topics * 10 partitions = 400 consumer connections at most (this is also the limit of the number of non-idle consumer apps you can run).

`+` 5 connections for producers = 405 client connections.

If you are using frameworks like Spring to create topics via `@Bean NewTopic`, then there will be another 40 connections from `AdminClient` classes, but these would likely start and end before the producer/consumer threads start.

There may be more connections to the cluster Controller, ConsumerGroupCoordinator and Fetch requests to in-sync replicas, if that is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for reply! So these many tcp connections or some thread which will reduce the number of actual connections? And as we have 9 brokers, so won't it limit to 9 connections at max per connections, i.e., 1 connection per broker?

Comment: I don't claim to know the exact TCP packets that the Kafka protocol sends, or how many. Fetch requests are made for each assigned partition, though, which could be more than one per broker.

Comment: Thanks for reply! But question was related to number of connections not number of packets. So, as I understood correctly from your explanation, each producer and each consumer will create its own connection and there will not be any common connection involved. Also, the number of connections will  be dependent on the number of partitions I have for topic in case of consumer and for producer as I am sharing a producer for multiple topics, so number of connection will be proportional to the number of brokers. Please correct me if understanding is incorrect.

Comment: Correct; producers, consumers, (and AdminClient) instances all establish separate threads and connections.  Then to send/receive messages, connections need to be made to individual partitions hosted by specific brokers.